# JavaFX: aligning elements with OS chrome (close/minimize/maximize buttons)

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

This is a question that stems from OS X features. I'm wondering if this is possible with JavaFX.

[image]

In the above image, I'm talking about the placement of the "Applications" and "+" buttons. Everything I've seen starts placing items directly below the "red/yellow/green" buttons.

I've only seen this with OS X applications and it probably doesn't translate well to windows/linux.